# Close jQuery Menu Operated by .slideToggle when Clicked Outside

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've seen a few similar questions but my menu open/close functionality is operated by slideToggle() rather than a class, and I'd rather not change my CSS to make it work.

I need the menu to close when the user clicks anywhere else on the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="select">
    <button class="select__selector">Reveal menu</button>
    <ul class="select__select">
        <li class="select__option"><a></a></li>
        <li class="select__option"><a></a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var langTrigger = jQuery('.select__selector');
var langList = jQuery('.select__select');

// Trigger active state.
langTrigger.click(function() {
    langTrigger.toggleClass('open');
    langList.slideToggle(200);
});

// Close list when page is loading.
langList.click(function() {
    langTrigger.click();
});
```

I've tried a few things but this was as close as I got.

```
if((langTrigger).hasClass('open')) {
     jQuery('body').on('click', function() {
         langList.css({display: 'none'});
     });
}
```

Comment: Please read about how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: Have you investigated how jQuery can handle an element losing focus?

Answer (score 1):

add a div and position it over your whole website like this:

```
<div class="overlay"</div>

.overlay{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

then something like this:

```
    $('.opensmenu').click(function(){
         $('.menu').toggle();
         $('.overlay').show();
    });

    $('.overlay').click(function(){
         $('.menu').hide();
         $(this).hide();
    });
```